# How to hide a div with jQuery based on the content from another div

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I am trying to hide a div element based on the short content from another div. 
Can anyone help with this?

**Here is an example:**

```
<div class="specs" id="div1">Dynamic Content</div>
<div class="specs" id="div2">Content 2</div>
<div class="specs" id="div3">Content 3</div>
<div class="specs" id="div4">Static Content</div> <!-- Hide this div element if #div1 content = 'Dynamic Content' -->
```

Basically I need to hide `#div4` if the content of `#div1 == 'Dynamic Content'`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the text to lowercase, and use [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) to remove possible whitespace:

```
if($.trim($('#div1').text().toLowerCase()) === 'dynamic content'){
    $('#div4').hide();
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xLc3z/)

Comment: Why convert to lowercase? Case may be important in the OP's case.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I guess we will have to hear from the OP. The string *may* be lowercase in some cases.. at least this approach is different from the other 3 answers as it will cover more cases.

Comment: The dynamic content will be entered by the user, so converting it to lower case is a good idea as only one if statement is needed. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#div4').css('display',($('#div1:contains("Dynamic Content")').length)?'none':'block')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LXVwV/)**

Comment: Very creative! I like it!

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($("#div1").html() === "Dynamic Content") {
  $("#div4").hide();
}
```

I will update this answer with more info if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the div in question contains the content, then hide the other content as required...

```
if( $('#div1:contains(Dynamic Content)').length ) {
    $('#div4').hide();
}
```